# fabric.js forcing the sizing of text within textareas

Tags: css, fabricjs

I have two boxes.

- Width - Landscape: 704px
- Width - Portrait: 421px

Both have: 
setFontSize: 50px

I would have hoped to see that the landscape can fit more content than the portrait but this is not the case (see below) that is all it allows me to add

I could be totally wrong but it seems to fit as a percentage of the area rather than an actual font-size?

Is there anyway I can force this to be different?

[image: Landscape]

[image: Portrait]

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: a [live example](http://codepen.io) would help us help you. Does the font uses the unit `em` (which are compounded, contrary to `rem`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at this example:

```
jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/w64bsnon/2/
```

If I understand you this is what you are looking for.